# matlab java interface--can not add the user-defined class to the Java class path

Tags: java, matlab

I coded a simple class: test and compiled it and put it in th

```
'D:\Dropbox\projects\ICPR2013\code\java\union_find'.
```

**Code:-**

```
public class test {
    public test() {
        System.out.printf("hello world!");
    }
}
```

And then I use the following code to bring the defined class to the Java class path. I also use `javaclasspath` to make sure that the folder including 'test' class is added to the Java class path.

```
javaaddpath('D:\Dropbox\projects\ICPR2013\code\java\union_find');
```

But when I use `x = javaObjectEDT('test');` to call the 'test' class, it gives me the following error: No class test can be located on Java class path

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853636/using-java-class-in-matlab/17857639#17857639). Basically check if you used the same java as matlab is using to compile your class. Also making jar files can help to bring java classes to matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your class is in the file called test.java, on Ubuntu 14.04 and Matlab 2013a, you can do as follows:

1. Compile your class file using java 6 (i.e. java version used in Matlab 2013a). Ubuntu 14.04 does not come with this java version. So you need to install it. Instructions are [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/install-oracle-java-6-7-or-8-ubuntu-14-04/).

   **/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/javac -d . test.java**
2. Make jar file:

   **/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/jar cf test.jar test.class**
3. Go to Matlab and add the jar file and run it:

   > > javaaddpath('/tmp/test.jar');
   > >     test()
   > >     hello world!

Hope this helps.

Comment: The java version is the issue. I use Java 8 to compiled the source code while the matlab uses Java 6